# Simple illustrator division of path/fill

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I know the question is simple, but had no luck finding existing solutions online.

I have a background rectangle with a fill color. The layer on top has closed paths (only strokes, no fill). How can I remove the background inside the closed paths, so it just goes around them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

1. Select the closed path and make a copy of it to the clipboard, if you need it later. Then select the background shape (=light brown), too.
2. Goto the Pathfinder panel (Window > Pathfinder) and click Minus; It's the 2nd from the left in the upper row in this Illustrator version.
3. Paste in place the closed path, if needed.